# ¿Qué se debe hacer con usuarios cuya descripción de perfil puede considerarse no adecuada?

Tags: discusión, soporte, convenciones-sociales, código-de-conducta

Navegando entre los perfiles de los usuarios me encontré con este usuario: [Tato broh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15514/tato-broh), el cual a mi parecer tiene una descripción de perfil muy poco adecuada para esta comunidad;

> Hola, soy un antisocial que se las pasa las 24h del día en la PC o durmiendo estoy deseando poder sacarle unas perrillas a esto de las páginas web y el javascript para emplearlo para darle dinero a los pobres y que así me quieran las niñas y les meta mi verga jajajaj, no mentira, en fin... como ya saben yo pregunto, pero no respondo, ya que si respondo me banean por ignorante. Que mas decir, juego maincrah 1.12 y me entretengo con un lápiz. Pasar de esta mierda de descripción ¿Pa qué os ponéis a leer? Mejor pasar y punto jajaj.

Creo que hay obvias razones para considerarla **no adecuada**, además estoy seguro no es el único, pues hace una semana o dos, me encontré con este otro usuario: [Danlos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21649/danlos), el cual se refería a "todos nosotros" como "nazis racistas" (entre muchos otros insultos xenófobos ) en comentarios de una pregunta que realizó (la cual fue eliminada gracias a los reportes de los usuarios), mis cuestiones en si son las siguientes;

> ¿Qué se debe hacer con usuarios como estos? 
>   ¿Existe alguna penalización permanente para los mismos?

Yo personalmente creo que si debería ya que son usuarios de tipo "troll" que no aportan nada a la comunidad.

Comment: Más bien parece ser sarcástico(Excepto las palabras conocidas como groserías), no le veo nada de malo en eso, pienso que mientras no haga daño alguno hacia otros usuarios está bien.

Comment: No intento ser troll, simplemente me limito a preguntar, y si no son útiles mis publicaciones aclarad cuales son vuestros problemas con ellas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de revisar las publicaciones del usuario [Tato broh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15514/tato-broh) y parece tener preguntas con puntaje positivo. Por esa parte, no parece ser un usuario tipo "troll" como dices, y si sus preguntas tienen votos positivos es porque de alguna manera aporta a la comunidad y la comunidad lo reconoce.

El tema central es el contenido de su perfil. Literalmente, la regla que tiene SO es que allí puedes colocar **lo que quieras**. Los moderadores tenemos poderes para editar los perfiles y la sección que indicas pero **solo si se violan las reglas de la compañía**, tal como se explica [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198064/182862):

> Nope. Unless the section blatantly violates the terms and conditions of the site, the About Me section should not be touched by anyone but the user

Traducido:

> No. A menos que la sección [Acerca De] viole descaradamente los términos y condiciones del sitio, la sección Acerca De no debería ser manipulada por nadie excepto por el usuario.

Si en la sección Acerca De encuentras contenido que viole los [términos y condiciones](http://stackexchange.com/legal) de StackOverflow o contenido que te parezca grosero, lo mejor será reportar alguna publicación del usuario con el motivo "Otro" e indicar en la descripción qué es lo que no te parece. Un moderador revisará el problema en cuestión y actuará acorde. Para el caso de Tato broh, edité su perfil para eliminar el contenido que considero grosero, gracias por la notificación.