# Votemos por contenido, no por personas

Tags: discusión, votos, voto-serial

Hay un usuario que está pidiendo a gritos ser baneado. Todos estamos de acuerdo y esperemos que le caiga pronto:

- porque es un usuario que en el pasado contribuyó activamente.
- porque actualmente está lanzando bilis.

Con un tiempo de reposo podría recapacitar y volver con un ánimo renovado.

Sin embargo, observo en su perfil de usuario que también se están votando negativamente sus publicaciones en el sitio principal (13 votos negativos en la última hora). Esas publicaciones tienen una calidad determinada y por ello se deben valorar. Votarlas porque pertenecen a una persona que ahora mismo está algo enajenada es hacer un flaco favor al sitio: ¿cómo sabrá alguien nuevo que acceda a la página por qué esa pregunta o respuesta es buena o mala si se votó por elementos externos?

Recoredemos: **votamos por la calidad de las publicaciones, no por la persona que las publicó**.

Comment: Se trata de [**Tato Broh**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15514/tato-broh). No entiendo porque la gente no habla claro. **¿Qué están esperando para banearlo?**. Esa actitud tan pasiva (_para no afectar al usuario_ supongo) daña más a la comunidad.

Comment: @toledano si omito su nombre es precisamente porque todos los que deben saberlo lo saben y mencionarlo en la publicación solo agravaría el problema dirigiendo más miradas a sus publicaciones. Creo que es más productivo gastar todos los reportes (bastante gente los hemos agotado por hoy) y buscar CM para gestionar la situación.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en que no tiene ninguna razón de ser votar -1 en una publicación que no se lo merece. Los votos son al contenido, no a la persona, y debería ser así tanto para estos casos como para cualquier publicación en el sitio.

Comment: Fedorqui, las cosas claras, es importante decir nombres y mostrar casos concretos. @toledano el usuario está baneado.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no estoy de acuerdo. Mi publicación surge a raíz de un caso concreto, pero aplica a todos los casos y a eso voy: es un recordatorio de la filosofía [se] que sus CM repiten continuamente ([ejemplo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238902/209901)). Consideré que añadir un enlace al usuario solo serviría para atraer más votos negativos innecesarios. Lo que viene siendo el [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235226/209901).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza a todo esto, ¡gracias por banearlo! Hemos creado multitud de reportes, pues dejó comentarios por todo.

Comment: Surge a partir de un caso concreto, pero no muestras evidencia al respecto. Considera que la comunidad es pequeña ahora, pero hacer un recordatorio como dices solo repercute en las pocas personas que conocen de lo que hablas. Para el resto de la comunidad, se habla en base a supuestos. Lo ideal es mostrar con ejemplos (los casos concretos). Adicional, no tomo tu gratitud a banearlo, porque no lo expusiste en esta pregunta que era lo que se debía hacer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lo que se debia hacer se hizo, que es reportar y avisar a los moderadores. El post en Meta no tiene por que mencionar al usuario especifico si va tras un perfil y una idea. No una persona

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza meditaré al respecto. Vengo de [so] donde constantemente se pide en Meta no dar detalles concretos para no caer en el _efecto Meta_ que perturba lo observado o empeora la situación. En cuanto al baneo: la finalidad de la publicación no era tampoco pedir un baneo, pues para esos hay otros medios que ya se usaron (reportes). El comentario anterior era un simple agredecimiento fuera de contexto, tómalo si quieres :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no estoy de acuerdo con llevarlo a un caso concreto. Creo que esta publicación tiene mucho más valor llevada a un genérico. Así como tampoco creo que se deba realizar una publicación en Meta para solicitar un ban. Ya bastantes publicaciones existen quejándose de situaciones particulares.

Comment: Yo había hecho un [post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051/qu%C3%A9-se-debe-hacer-con-usuarios-como-estos) hace tiempo en el que realmente "no me prestaron" atención con dicho usuario ...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La verdad es que quedé un poco desconcertado por tu comentario. En especial donde mencionás "*no lo expusiste en esta pregunta que era lo que se debía hacer*"... Teniendo en cuenta que este comentario fue mientras todavía quedaban pendientes reportes de irrespetuosos/abusivos a moderador (y algunos siguen pendientes hasta ahora) que algunos hicimos. Por ejemplo en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29421/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-chat-con-xmlhttprequest#comment126001_29421),

Comment: *[cont]* [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30691/c%c3%b3mo-leer-y-guardar-un-archivo-con-jquery-con-el-fin-de-hacer-un-chat#comment125998_30691) o en [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68883/127), cuando veo que sí eliminaste a otros que se encontraban al lado. Sé que hiciste un excelente trabajo como moderador, y podía entender que, como quedaste solo, te haya sobrepasado la situación o que no tuvieras tiempo, pero no puedo entender cómo es que no estás revisando los reportes que van camino a quedar vencidos cuando sí estás online y moderando.

Comment: *[cont]* ¿Esta es una forma de protestar o de rebelarte ante alguna situación? Y si es así, ¿no deberías publicarlo en Meta para que la comunidad lo entienda, pueda reaccionar acorde a eso, y no recaiga la responsabilidad sobre tus acciones? Porque lo que veo es que protegiste [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1050/127), a lo que no le veo el sentido, pero aún tenemos lenguaje irrespetuoso/abusivo en el sitio. ¿O cómo deberíamos tratarlo?

Comment: Para casi todo tiene que haber excepciones. Aquí tenemos un ejemplo de [votar por la persona](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10567/48225) (aunque también por el excelente contenido). Bueno, si algún día Odersky, Stroustrup o Gosling publicasen aquí tampoco pasaría nada porque les votásemos más que a otros usuarios :)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos buena esta. También pasó con [Alan Kay respondiendo a una pregunta sobre qué dijo él en un momento dado y respondiendo que "no se acuerda"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389642/1983854). Lleva 350 votos :D

Comment: Pido disculpas por lo que hice, igual creo que tampoco se puede discriminar por minusvalía.

Comment: @DrCristianstein es bueno verte de vuelta. Ojalá tu presencia sea productiva para todos y vengas con muchas ganas de aprender cosas!

Answer (score -4):

De manera normal, se vota por el contenido, **nunca por las personas**. Lo que hizo Tato Broh no cae en lo que podemos llamar un comportamiento normal. Si entiendo correctamente al votar en negativo, perdió el privilegio de seguir comentando. Los usuarios actuamos de esta manera, ante lo que parecía la inacción de los moderadores.

Como ya pasó, por favor no generalicen. **Siempre se vota por el contenido, nunca por las personas**.

Pero los casos extraordinarios, requieren de medidas extraordinarias. Es solo un usuario, son solo 13 publicaciones, tampoco es para tanto.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Estás diciendo que, en este caso particular, era correcto votar por la persona en vez del contenido debido a las circunstancias "especiales"?

Comment: @sstan, no se puede votar por las personas. No hay en los perfiles o en las tarjetas flechitas de votos. Por lo tanto, decir que se vota por personas, es una forma de explicar otra cosa. La publicación de fedorqui dice que no se debe votar una publicación, solo porque una persona te cae bien o mal (porque el voto puede ser positivo o negativo), sino por la publicación. En este caso, los votos negativos en las publicaciones (que tal vez no merecían ese negativo) ayudaron a detener un comportamiento indeseado. Creo que dije lo mismo, pero con otras palabras. Ustedes disculpen, es __luna llena__.

Comment: En realidad sí se puede votar por la persona en cierto sentido, y eso es precisamente a lo que se refiere fedorqui. Si vas al perfil del usuario, verás que hay una serie de votos negativos aplicadas a varias publicaciones pasadas, incluyendo el sitio en inglés. Esto para mi es una forma de votar por la persona, no la publicación. Y sin importar el comportamiento de este usuario, eso no es correcto.

Comment: No @sstan, solo hay una forma de votar. Haciendo clic en las flechitas. Y solo las publicaciones tienen esas flechitas. Lo demás son percepciones personales y por supuesto, soy muy respetables.

Comment: Puede que siempre se vote por contenido, pero se ven casos en los que se vota por la persona... y no sólo el usuario del que habláis. En el chat de vez en cuando se ven conversaciones del tipo "me quedan votos para hoy, ¿alguien necesita alguno?" o "Hey X, ¿tienes alguna pregunta que no tenga votos?" (No son citas textuales)

Comment: Claro @AlvaroMontoro, las motivaciones o las razones para votar son innumerables. Y sin duda votar por las razones equivocadas es más frecuente de lo que pensamos. Yo mismo me he visto votando por razones equivocadas y luego hago malabares para poder retirar mi voto. ¿Todos los votos son a las personas? No. Solo algunos. ¿Todos los votos están correctamente fundamentados? Esperemos que si. ¿Se pueden contabilizar los "votos a las personas"? No creo, a menos que sean seriales. Lo del Tato fue un caso especial que no es representativo de nada, no representa nada. Un mal rato, tal vez.

Comment: Parte de esta comunidad está muy verde si considera que los insultos son casos extraordinarios que requieren medidas extraordinarias. Es algo que conocen bien en el sitio en inglés y que tienen bien definido como manejar : Respuesta a [Offensive comments - How to deal with these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274304/956880)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos tienes razón en que el sitio en inglés está más avanzado que esté... También tiene 10 años más (que en años de Internet es como 100) mientras que nosotros solo estamos empezando. Comparados con ellos apenas somos un bebé dando sus primeros pasos y que aún no está muy coordinado. Está bien aplicar nuestra experiencia en otros sitios de SE, pero debemos ser pacientes.

Comment: Está bien votar por personas en casos extraordinarios. Por norma general si alguien insulta como yo hice habría que darle un -1 a todas sus publicaciones.