# Pregunta cerrada con votos negativos en mi opinion no fueron puestos por la pregunta en si

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas, respuestas-borradas

Hoy me encontré con -85 y pensé que se habria eliminado algún usuario. El caso es que indagando fue que se pidió eliminar mi respuesta a esta pregunta:

[¿Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65300/83)

Bajo mi punto de vista (quizás pueda o sea que como soy el afectado no estoy de acuerdo con ello) la pregunta no es mala como tal, el caso es y se sabe que los votos negativos fueron por el comportamiento que tuvo el usuario, (no entro en si es correcto o no). Recientemente @fedorqui dejó una [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1935/votemos-por-contenido-no-por-personas) sobre este tipo de acciones.

Esta pregunta es para saber si hace falta pedir que la pregunta sea reabierta, o directamente alguien la puede abrir. Basándose en lo comentado anteriormente, los votos negativos no son consecuentes con la pregunta en sí.

Solo es mi opinion, sí, sé que la puedo proponer para reabrir, pero estamos en las mismas de por qué se cerro etc. Además de la influencia que puede tener para recuperar el ver una puntuación de -7.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. La pregunta es mala, pero la respuesta muy buena y eso justifica por sí solo que el bloque pregunta-respuesta se mantenga. A veces borramos con demasiada ligereza.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por contestar, aunque realmente so es una pregunta tan mala, en mi opinion, pues si se podria mejorar, pero como preguntas que quieres usar el giroscopio si ni siquiera sabes que eso se puede hacer mucho menos como se llama lo que permite hacer eso, y sobre poner codigo mas de lo mismo, fedorqui no se mal interprete mi comentario, te entiendo y hasta cierto punto estoy con tigo, solo aclaro el porque no creo que sea tan mala. P.D: gracias por lo de muy buena respuesta.Saludos

Comment: Eso sí, es verdad que este usuario no ha sido demasiado respetuoso con la comunidad. Ahora bien, parece que poco a poco sus preguntas cumplen con los estándares e incluso acepta respuestas ([véase la última](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66214/83)).

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por pedir la reapertura, yo no quiero hacerlo pues estoy implicado y puede parecer que es por los puntos (85), aunque son importantes no es el centro, pues seguro que muchas de mis respuesta no han sido ni votas ni acceptadas por el usuario que las formula (igual que les pasara a otros usuarios no solo a mi) lo que quiero expresar es que no es por los puntos en si, borrare este comentario, solo era por si ve que no voto en la reapertura. P.D si asumi que fue usted, quizas me equivoco. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel ¿Estás/estabas opinando que se reabra o que se **recupere**? Es decir, ¿la discusión es por qué fue cerrada o por qué fue eliminada? Creo que se están confundiendo los términos, o yo no termino de entender a qué se apunta.

Comment: @AngelAngel Me parece suigeneris la pregunta que indicas, tiene -8 la pregunta y 9 la respuesta. Definitivamente la pregunta es mala pero la respuesta es excelente como las que realizas.Que bueno que se recupero la pregunta, pero creo que el usuario debería modificarla un poco para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores.

Comment: Mira qué bien, se acaba de borrar la pregunta otra vez ([timeline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65300/timeline)).

Comment: @fedorqui y recuperada xD

Comment: @Jorgesys dices  "Que bueno que se recupero la pregunta"  pero votas para eliminar? :/

Comment: No te preocupes lois 6b, ya no hay ningún eliminar como puedes ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65300/es-posible-saber-cuando-rotas-el-m%C3%B3vil-en-unity

Comment: @Jorgesys ya pero me pareció muy extraño .. :O

Comment: Con todo respeto por quien pregunta acá, yo sí estoy totalmente en contra de responder ese tipo de preguntas, y considero que la buena respuesta no salva la pregunta, lo que hace en mi opinión es "darle alas" a otros usuarios a que hagan preguntas igual de malas, pues finalmente va a aparecer alguien que va a hacerles el trabajo.

Comment: Considero que dada la gran calidad de la respuesta, la pregunta deberia ser borrada, deberia crearse una nueva pregunta por @AngelAngel redactada como corresponde, y con esta misma respuesta.

Comment: @Shaz interesante reflexión. De todos modos, si me apuras el daño ya está "hecho" y eliminarla no afecta a quien la publicó. La respuesta ya se publicó y el que la preguntó ya se benefició de ella. La opción que tenemos es la de pulir esa pregunta para que una buena pregunta sea de utilidad para la gente que la encuentre en el futuro.

Comment: @fedorqui sin duda es una característica en la que creo que estamos cortos: faltan editores, usuarios que estén buscando activamente mejorar la calidad de las publicaciones... Sin embargo, ¿no te parece que esta tarea debería caer más en quienes respondieron, votan por mantener abierta o por recuperar, y no tanto en quienes optan por cerrarla/eliminarla?

Comment: @Mariano absolutamente. Sin embargo, mejorar preguntas y respuestas es algo que ocurre orgánicamente: a medida que las encuentras, intentas mejorarlas. Ahora que tengo privilegios para ver preguntas eliminadas observo con preocupación que [se están eliminando muchísimas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) por parte de un grupo pequeño de usuarios sin que se haya conseguido un consenso aquí en Meta. Me recuerda [casos parecidos en SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282921/1983854) que resultan bastante preocupantes. Eliminar por eliminar no me gusta.

Comment: @fedorqui Excelente ejemplo y muy personalizado :-) Sí, es exactamente lo mismo que pienso. Son temas que hay que resolver (y que hace mucho algún moderador solía tomar como tarea personal), sobre todo con primeas publicaciones que son eliminadas (con todo el perjuicio que implica eso)... Ahora bien, creo que este caso es diferente, como también me parece que la acción de Shaz está más que justificada. Realmente creo que el foco estaría en los otros que nombré (pero ya es tema para otra publicación)... Es decir, también me parece importante eliminar contenido que da un mal ejemplo.

Comment: @Mariano abramos un hilo aparte para discutirlo e intentar llegar a consenso :) Lo bueno de borrar la pregunta es que aumenta la velocidad con la que el usuario puede quedar baneado de preguntar. Lo malo es lo que comenté antes: él ya obtuvo su solución, el más perjudicado es la comunidad pues pierde una buena respuesta. Borrar por borrar sin tener en cuenta la calidad de la respuesta me parece algo imprudente. Probablemente si tuviéramos Documentation en [es.so] todo esto podría resolverse moviendo el buen contenido allí.

Comment: @fedorqui tengo mis reservas sobre Documentation (para mí no funciona)... Estamos de acuerdo en el objetivo final, no en el camino hacia éste. También estoy de acuerdo en que una buena respuesta eleva la vara de la pregunta... Pero hay muchísimas alternativas para que no se pierda el contenido. Me parece que son más sanas

Comment: **Relacionada** (secuela): [Es posible bloquear esta pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1987/127)

Answer (score 8):

Yo voté para cerrar, hice downvote y tambien voté para eliminar.

La cosa es que un novato en el sitio puede hacer preguntas malas por desconocimiento, pero este usuario lleva meses y casi 100 preguntas .

Considero que la pregunta no es de calidad y pese a los comentarios y conversaciones con él no la editó .

**Sin embargo** la respuesta es muy buena. Le comenté al que respondió al igual que comentaria a cualquier respuesta en una pregunta de esa calidad:

> No conviene responder a preguntas que van a ser cerradas porque el autor no ha mostrado ni lo que ha intentado y se promueve el que se sigan haciendo ya que "ya habrá alguien que me responda"

---

<sub>Nota: dado la buena calidad de la respuesta, la reflexion originada tras esta pregunta y ver que el usuario está mostrando cambios en sus conductas (gracias al [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg/1943#comment5812_1942) de Fedorqui), tambien voto para la recuperación de la pregunta.</sub>

Comment: Tienes razón en que se da un mensaje equivocado contestando a preguntas sin ningún esfuerzo. Supongo que la filosofía podría ser: cerrarlas lo más rápido posibles, incluso borrarlas. Pero si hay respuestas buenas, cerrarlas igualmente pero mantenerlas para que la respuesta luzca.

Comment: Si, lo ya muchas veces comentado, que no hay cierres tan rapidos como se quisiera, y ahora en breves requiriendo 3k de rep para ello va a afectar bastante. Un tema peliagudo. Entonces, ¿puede una excelente respuesta salvar una pesima pregunta?

Comment: si no me parece "mal"  tu forma de actuar cada uno actua como "cree conveniente" yo no critico lo de cerrar y down, aunque si que me choca un poco la eliminacion, primero y obviamente porque me afecta, pero mas alla de eso, aunque la pregunta sea de un usuario esa misma pregunta y la respuesta en si, puede ayudar a otros en un futuro, asi que la pregunta es de todos, pero que no me parece mal su forma de actuar, ahora hago un copy-paste sobre lo que deje en otro comentario de porque no creo que sea tan mala pregunta

Comment: *aunque realmente no es una pregunta tan mala, en mi opinion, pues si se podria mejorar, pero como preguntas que quieres usar el giroscopio si ni siquiera sabes que eso se puede hacer mucho menos como se llama lo que permite hacer eso, y sobre poner codigo mas de lo mismo, no se mal interprete mi comentario*

Comment: @lois6b gracias por contestar. Saludos

Comment: *¿puede una excelente respuesta salvar una pesima pregunta?* existe una medalla para eso se llama creo reversion o  algo asi, pero si se eliminan ese tipo de preguntas, quien la tendria. Saludos

Comment: Tal vez existan otras posibilidades: 1) modificar la pregunta para que sea válida, aún a costa de cambiarla completamente. 2) plantear una pregunta nueva para encajar la respuesta que se dio en esa pregunta mala original. Lo de 1) puede ser útil, pero el que preguntó originalmente puede quejarse de que estamos manoseando demasiado su pregunta, además de hacerle el trabajo sucio; lo de 2) me encaja mejor, aunque lo mismo queda algo ortopédico crear una pregunta a partir de una respuesta. No sé...

Comment: @fedorqui pense lo que dices... pero yo tuve una conversacion por chat privado con el usuario en cuestion para que cambiara una pregunta y no lo hizo. se cerró, él la eliminó y la volvió a preguntar exactamente igual . si la quiere cambiar alguien o él perfecto pero yo  no xDD

Comment: *dado (...)y ver que el usuario está mostrando cambios en sus conductas (gracias al comentario de Fedorqui), tambien voto para la recuperación de la pregunta*. Los otros motivos que mencionas son válidos. Pero que el usuario cambie o no en su conducta nunca debiera influir en tu decisión de votar en una pregunta. [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1935/votemos-por-contenido-no-por-personas)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos si, tienes razón. pero lo hago por la gran calidad de la respuesta principalmente, lo demás es un añadido

Answer (score 1):

Observo con estupefacción que la pregunta tiene tres votos a favor:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vale que la publicación recibió muchos votos negativos y tal vez no es necesario votar a partir de cierto límite (acepto mi culpa). Pero ¿de verdad es justificable votar positivo por "pena" o por compensar votos negativos?

El botón de votar positivo dice:

> Esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara

y el de votar negativo:

> Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil (hacer clic de nuevo para deshacer la acción)

A mi entender, esta pregunta no reúne ninguna de las características que promueven el voto positivo.

Recordemos: [**Votemos por contenido, no por personas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83).