# Las preguntas en meta con las cuales se quiere exponer un caso o similar

Tags: discusión, meta, respuesta-aceptada

Las preguntas en Meta que apuntan a exponer un caso concreto, o que son una pregunta directa, como por ejemplo:

> **Pregunta:** ¿Puede uno abrir varias cuentas para votar en sus
>   preguntas?

> **Respuesta:** *Usuario responde no porque...*

---

deberían marcar el check de aceptación.

Me refiero a que está muy claro: marcas la que creas que responde mejor a tu duda y obviamente que esté bien.

**Pero este es un caso diferente:**

[Pregunta cerrada con votos negativos en mi opinion no fueron puestos por la pregunta en si](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg)

Yo publiqué esa pregunta en la cual se exponía un caso *(Gracias a todos los que comentaron sus ideas, etc.)* y [@lois6b](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) [publicó una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1943/127). Lo cierto es que marcarla como check no me parece lo más correcto porque, estando o no de acuerdo, otro usuario podría expresar otra cosa con la que pueda estar de acuerdo en más puntos, o simplemente no estar de acuerdo en nada, y poder pensar "*por qué la de él tiene el check*" por ejemplo... o aunque no se publique ninguna respuesta más, no sé si el check sería correcto de usar en este tipo de preguntas.

Sí, sé que puedo dejar de hacer check, cada uno es libre, pero no me gustaría, estar haciendo algo que no es "*correcto*". En este caso, por una percepción mía, me gustaría conocer algunas opiniones, o cómo barajan este tipo de situaciones, pues a mí ya me ha sucedido otras veces de verme en esta situación.

Comment: Meta tiene una política muchísimo más laxa con la aceptación de respuestas, y más aún en las de [meta-tag:discusión]. Esto es lógicamente muy diferente a las de [meta-tag:soporte] (como el primer ejemplo que diste). Obviamente no hay necesidad alguna de aceptar la respuesta, y por cómo estás argumentando que "no te parece lo más correcto" (sea el motivo que sea), te recomendaría no aceptarla... Dicho esto, está claro que conocés cuáles son las opciones, por lo que te diría que estás equivocado en pensar que "no es lo correcto"... No veo mucho que pueda discutirse en este caso.

Comment: No tienes por que marcar mi respuesta. hahah de hecho fue un comentario demasiado extenso que converti a respuesta HAHA Es una pregunta de [tag:discusion]. Yo tambien tengo preguntas que no marqué respuesta porque aunque sus respuestas están bien, no hay nada que "aceptar". Cada uno dio su opinion  ^^