# ¿Podríamos bloquear la pregunta "¿Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity?"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, pregunta-bloqueada

**Intentaré ser breve**.

Se trató el tema en 
[Pregunta cerrada con votos negativos en mi opinion no fueron puestos por la pregunta en si](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg)

---

Se reabrió esa pregunta, hoy vuelvo ha ver que la [vuelven a eliminar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65300/es-posible-saber-cuando-rotas-el-m%C3%B3vil-en-unity), por eso me preguntaba si sería posible proteger esta pregunta o algo similar.

---

Se decida lo que se decida, mi idea no es volver a sacar otra vez el tema, mejor invertir ese tiempo en aprender otra cosa, que muchas cosas son la que uno puede aprender, con el tiempo que se emplea en algunas cosas.

Comment: @Mariano he dividido la pregunta en este hilo -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1988/me-pregunto-como-la-gente-consigue-la-medalla-reversion-cuando-es-posible-cerra Saludos

Comment: @Mariano *...creo que no deberíamos prohibir nuevas respuestas en una publicación algo joven*
pero si la publicacion esta eliminada, no creo que se puedan
publicar nuevas respuesta, aqui se podria mirar que es peor
el remedio o la enfermedad, o simplemente recuperarle o dejarla cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Amplié en mi respuesta (hablo del hipotético donde se recupere), pero mantuve el comentario porque creo que se podría cambiar el término "proteger" por "bloquear"

Comment: @Rub veo que estuviste mirando estas etiquetas. ¿Te parece que usáramos [meta-tag:publicación-bloqueada] para que así también se pueda poner en la pregunta [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/83)?

Comment: @fedorqui Tan me parece que ya cree la etiqueta (pensé que ya la había agregado a la pregunta que mencionas)

Answer (score 7):

Yo no tengo una opinión formada sobre si hay que eliminar, dejar cerrada o dejar abierta a la pregunta. Y creo que esa discusión pertenece a [tu primera publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1942/127).

- <sup>No tengo la suficiente experiencia en Unity como para evaluar la calidad de la pregunta, pero sí he encontrado argumentos muy válidos para recuperarla (expuestos en tu otra publicación en Meta), como argumentos totalmente válidos en [comentarios de @Shaz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg#comment5837_1942) ("*la buena respuesta no salva la pregunta, lo que hace en mi opinión es "darle alas" a otros usuarios a que hagan preguntas igual de malas*"). Tu respuesta es muy buena, no hay duda de eso.</sup>

Si se definiera recuperarla, creo que la publicación es un tanto joven como para [bloquearla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/127), más aún teniendo en cuenta que el autor de esa pregunta, si bien la aceptó, tuvo algunas reservas (aunque algo confusas):

> Lo que pasa Angel, eso detecta si voy hacia derecha puedo hacer *una acción* y si voy hacia la izquierda *hace otra accion* ?
>   Me refiero, he puesto lo que has puesto arriba y funciona, mi objeto rota, pero si giro para la izquierda que haga algo y si giro a la derecha que haga otra, accion eso es posible?

Creo que corresponde que (si se llegara a recuperar) se mantenga la posibilidad de que otro pueda responderla, **no bloquearla**. En cambio, una opción interesante sería **que un moderador agregue una nota** aclarando que se discutió en Meta, y que se trate ahí antes de votar para eliminar.

Pero...

### ¡Salvemos el contenido antes de seguir cerrando, eliminando y volviendo a abrir!

Este es el espíritu que creo que más deberíamos fomentar en SOes. Generar contenido de calidad incluye editar contenido para mejorarlo. Es algo que invito a que todos intenten realizar más frecuentemente: *editar, editar, editar, editar, editar, editar, editar*... Incluso cuando la edición no respete fielmente la publicación original, un experto puede saber qué modificar para cambiar la pregunta, mejorarla, y apuntar a los mismos conceptos teóricos necesarios para responderla.

En este caso en particular, quizás se deba reflexionar: todos los que respondieron y votaron para dejar abierta/recuperar deberían estar en condiciones de poder mejorar la pregunta. Es un excelente ejemplo para ver que si, en vez de seguir discutiendo qué deberíamos hacer, se mejorara la pregunta, ¡sería un tema finalizado!

En otros casos, en otras preguntas, creo que todos los que responden podrían peguntarse si no hay algo para emprolijar en la pregunta.

**- Editen**. Es lo que yo hago.

Comment: Muy cierto. Por cierto, ya tiene mi voto de _recuperar_... el voto castigo en este contexto es incomprensible.. a la par de nuestra cultura latina.

Comment: @EmanuelVe "el voto castigo" sería el -1 a la pregunta por no investigación/poco útil? O sería el voto a eliminar para no dar el mal ejemplo?

Comment: Ambos Mariano, veo mucha gente avalanzandose a votar, cerrar y eliminar. El foco deberia ser mas como lo que hizo AngelAngel, contestar y compartir su conocimiento. Y editar, si una pregunta puede salvarse, es mejor salvarla.

Comment: @Mariano ...que el autor de esa pregunta no la aceptó... creo recordar que el usuario si la acepto, aunque ahora al estar eliminada no aparece y no se si despues quito el check o por estar eliminada no aparece, sobre el otro punto ...Lo que pasa Angel, eso detecta si voy hacia derecha puedo hacer una acción y si voy hacia la izquierda hace otra accion ?... el aclara que si le funciono y si se fija en la pregunta original no menciona nada de lo que comenta en su comentario, o por lo menos de esa manera si que menciona algo de 90º...

Comment: ...pero al poner despues **es decir** sumado al resto de su pregunta y titulo, lo interpreto como que lo que le interesa principalmente es saber como mover el objeto, aun asi le respondo algo en los comentarios. *...que si es posible pero mejor que abra otra pregunta...*, cosa que nunca hizo o yo no vi que lo hiciera, si tengo tiempo y ganas despues intentare editar la pregunta, aunque es algo complicado pues necesito saber algunos datos para determinar como quiere o cuando quiere que se rote ect. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Se ha **bloqueado** la publicación de forma permanente. No debería poder eliminarse ni editarse por los usuarios, así como tampoco poder editarse parte de dicho contenido.

Motivos:

- **La pregunta es mala para el sitio**. Además, el autor sigue sin comprender que dicha pregunta, tal como luce, está fuera de los estándares de calidad de las preguntas que se requieren en el sitio. Sobre esto, lastimosamente no se puede hacer más, puesto que ha tenido bastante tiempo para editar el contenido de la pregunta, sin embargo no lo ha hecho (y por lo visto no tiene planes de cambiarlo).
- Por otro lado, **la respuesta es buena** (fuera del tiempo y esfuerzo invertido, toda buena respuesta contiene estos dos factores) y sería bueno mantenerla en el sitio para futuros usuarios.
- La comunidad no decide qué hacer con la pregunta. El historial muestra lo siguiente:

  - Cerrar la pregunta
  - Eliminar la pregunta
  - Recuperar la pregunta
  - Eliminar nuevamente la pregunta
  - Tratar de recuperar la pregunta

Nota: a futuro, este tipo de publicaciones **no deberían existir** y los usuarios veteranos deberíamos evitar responder este tipo de publicaciones que sabemos que quedarán en un debate largo y tendido.

---

Se ha cambiado el tipo de bloqueo. Se está agregando información sobre el bloqueo de publicaciones para mayor comprensión por parte de la comunidad ante estas situaciones.

Más información:

- [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/227)

Comment: @AngelAngel para este caso, creo que la única persona que debería editar esa pregunta para agregar más información es el OP. Si otro usuario agrega más información de lo pensado y la pregunta no es wiki, entonces lo más probable es que se deba publicar una nueva pregunta. Así funciona el sitio. Si Mariano u otro usuario quiere agregar información extra, hacerlo con cuidado.

Comment: Me parece muy bien que se haya publicado esta respuesta explicando los motivos por los cuales se bloqueó la pregunta, sin embargo, coincido con Mariano que no de debió haberse bloqueado, pues esto provoca que la respuesta no pueda ser votada.

Comment: @Rubén ese es el objetivo: ni la pregunta ni la respuesta deben ser votadas. Se debe entender que esta pregunta no es de calidad para el sitio, a pesar que la respuesta sí lo sea. Tal como funciona el sitio, si se bloquea la pregunta también las respuestas (puedes pedir una nueva funcionalidad al respecto en MetaSE). Era bloquear la publicación o mantenerla eliminada por ser una mala pregunta.

Comment: Si usted dice -> *...ni la pregunta ni la respuesta deben ser votadas. Se debe entender que esta pregunta no es de calidad para el sitio...* en su respuesta a @Ruben, le invito a responder a esta otra pregunta -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1988/me-pregunto-como-la-gente-consigue-la-medalla-reversion-cuando-es-posible-cerra de aplicar eso mismo a todas las preguntas "malas" quien tendria esa medalla, en ingles la tienen muchos, la unica solucion seria que se cumplan los requisitos de upvote y downvote antes de que alguno se le ocurra el bloquearla. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel la estoy respondiendo. El problema en la pregunta de SOen es que careces de la reputación suficiente para ver que es una respuesta unificada y las demás respuestas fueron eliminadas. Y este es un caso meramente excepcional, no como el de la pregunta que citas. La causa de todo este problema es: si detectamos que la pregunta carece de calidad para el sitio, **evitemos responderla**, en su lugar comentemos para que sea una pregunta de calidad y tenga respuestas de calidad. Una pregunta mala con una buena respuesta es un problema grave para el sitio.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza creo que se equivoca con su comentario y a cual esta respondiendo me imagino que estara respondiendo a la de los tipos de "bloqueadas" que existen, yo hablo que si se aplica el eliminar o bloquear las preguntas "malas" pues yo no creo que esta en cuestion sea tan mala, quien tendria la medalla reversion le dejo el [link anterior](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1988/me-pregunto-como-la-gente-consigue-la-medalla-reversion-cuando-es-posible-cerra) otra vez

Comment: @Rubén el historial de dicha pregunta muestra que la comunidad ha optado por: 1) cerrar, 2) eliminar, 3) recuperar, 4) eliminar de nuevo, 5) tratar de recuperar. Pues que la comunidad tiene una opinión dividida, el moderador actúa en estas situaciones de manera imparcial y aplica un bloqueo. Estoy traduciendo https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/182862 para explicar esto allí y no duplicar la info.

Comment: @Rubén la pregunta permanece bloqueada para que no la cierren/voten/eliminen. La respuesta sigue siendo editable/votable/etc. Si no te parece el bloqueo, puedes re reportar la pregunta y otro moderador revisará el caso en cuestión (si el reporte lo reviso yo nuevamente pierde todo el sentido)

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene demasiados comentarios, he borrado algunos, pero sigue siendo extenso.