# Normas a la hora de sugerir fuentes de información en internet

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, enlaces

Me he encontrado muchas veces buscando en internet la solución a mis problemas, y una que otra vez buscando la de otros. Muchas veces veo cualquier solución en algún foro y la doy por válida, pero al dar esta solución a otros me preguntaron si la había sacado de un sitio oficial.

Así que mi pregunta es ésta: ¿de qué sitios web me puedo auxiliar y establecer como referencia a la hora de dar una solución lo más oficial y confiable posible?

Supongo que GitHub y Stack Overflow son los bastante seguros. ¿Hay más recursos de los que me pueda auxiliar?

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que no hay ninguna norma... y la verdad no entiendo que buscas... Sé que Python y Django tienen un sitio oficial que aloja su documentación y son la referencia oficial proporcionada por la fundación respectiva de cada proyecto... pero mejor no sigo, porque no entiendo.

Comment: Mas o menos a eso me refiero: sitios oficiales. Este 'problema' me surgio cuando intente sugerirle a alguien un sitio para que se documentara, a lo que me dijeron que si era un sitio confiable. Me parecio razonable el comentario, ya que no creo que escribir en google la misma pregunta que puso, he indicarlo cualquier sitio que hable sobre el tema sea muy productivo. Me refiero a que sitios se consideran mas 'oficiales' o 'confiables' que otros.

Comment: Oficial y confiable no son sinónimos. Muchos lenguajes o implementaciones tienen sitios oficiales. Se me ocurre, por ejemplo, JavaScript. Tanto Google, Mozilla como Microsoft tienen cada uno referencias oficiales a JavaScript... además del estándar. En StackOverflow encontrarás respuestas confiables a problemas sobre JavaScript, pero no es "oficial"... No creo que haya una respuesta genérica a tu pregunta, tipo _one size fits all_. Tal vez si tu solicitud fuera más precisa o tuvieras un ejemplo concreto...

Comment: Si por ejemplo te digo 'mira aqui : https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/24270/como-puedo-ejecutar-varios-comandos-en-una-sola-linea-en-powershell' a mi en lo personal no me inspira mucha confianza 'enmimaquinafunciona.com' (mas alla de que el sitio que he utilizado de ejemplo sea valido o brinde respuestas acertadas), es a la hora de sugerir material del internet, me preguntaba si habia una norma que te 'calificaba' tu respuesta en base a que tan confiable fuera los recursos que brindas para informarse mas.

Comment: Con confiable me refiero: la wikipedia no es un sitio confiable, mas alla de que muchos usuarios la utilicen y den por hecho que la informacion brindada alli es valida o no

Comment: En sentido general lo que pregunto, es que si la comunidad stackoverflow tiene alguna 'politica' sobre esto, algo asi como: 'valida que tus sitios sean oficiales antes de publicar nada', o 'pon tantos ejemplos como puedas para que las personas se informen por si mismas, y que decidan ellas mismos por la validez de la informacion brindada'

Comment: Cada vez que leí esta pregunta interpreté algo diferente. ¿Estás preguntando enlaces a qué sitios se pueden poner en una respuesta que escribas dentro de [es.so]? ¿O estás preguntando qué sitios son confiables dentro de todos los sitios que hay en internet? ¿O estás preguntando cuál es la etiqueta (formato recomendado) al momento de citar una fuente en tu respuesta? ¿Está claro que escribir "mira [enlace]" no es una respuesta? ¿Podrías agregar un enlace a tu respuesta y el comentario que te llevó a preguntar esto?

Comment: Tenemos conceptos diferentes de lo que son fuentes confiables. Dices que la Wikipedia no es confiable pero que GitHub sí, ¿por qué? Ambos sitios cuentan con contenido añadido por usuarios, pero la Wikipedia tiene editores, moderadores, requerimiento de fuentes... que GitHub no tiene. Me fiaría mucho más de un artículo de la Wikipedia que del repositorio de un usuario "desconocido" en GitHub. Y mencionas Free Code Camp como fiable, para serte sincero, es la primera vez que oigo sobre ese sitio web (no digo que no sea confiable, solo lo pongo como ejemplo de lo relativo que es el tema)

Comment: `pero al dar esta solución a otros me preguntaron si la había sacado de un sitio oficial` ... Ten cuidado con el bulling de oficina. No quiero desviar la discusión, pero un developer con experiencia no te haría esa pregunta ... salvo que quiera deshacerse de ti ;| ...tal vez la pregunta viene de un jefe **que no es un developer**. En ese caso puedes: o bien explicarle como todo esto de la programación se rige por la incertidumbre o simplemente calmarlo diciendo le que siempre que te es posible, aplicas las mejores practicas (lo mas recomendable, en la mayoría de los casos).

Comment: En lo personal yo como programador me auxilio principalmente de SO y de GitHub, por supuesto que a la hora de buscar informacion cualquier sitio me sirve, siempre y cuando compruebe que la informacion brindada sea valida. Lo que digo que para mi la informacion brindada en estos 2 sitios es lo bastante confiable, ya que una comunidad grande de programadores corroboran, votan y opinan sobre una respuesta dada. Entiendo tambien que no necesariamente la informacion brindada en estos 2 sitios sea correcta, y que terminos 'confiable' y 'segura' sean terminos bastantes relativos.

Comment: Queria principalmente una guia o patron que me podrian sugerir a la hora de referenciar otras fuentes de informacion. como dije anteriormente :`valida que tus sitios sean oficiales antes de publicar nada', o 'pon tantos ejemplos como puedas para que las personas se informen por si mismas, y que decidan ellas mismos por la validez de la informacion brindada` queria saber cual de estos dos enfoques es mas acertado. O si simplemente noes algo de lo que preocuparse

Comment: Si lo que buscas son fuentes confiables, sugiero que te apoyes de la **documentación oficial** de cada tecnología, lo demás solo es información repartida en el cyber-espacio (que pueden o no hacer referencia al sitio oficial de esas tecnologías)

Comment: Entiendo que quizas mi pregunta para algunos carezca de sentido, para mi SO esta enfocada a ayudar a solucionar problemas de la comunidad de programadores. Con brindar informacion e intentar ayudar debe ser suficiente (sin caer en ser completamente inutil en la busqueda de la solucion). Lo que busco son buenas practicas (si hay sobre este tema), para asi adoptarlas he intentar acoplarme mejor a como SO brinda soluciones y alternativas a problemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hasta ahora, lo que mencionas como **sitio de respuestas oficiales** me parece extraño, especialmente en el mundo de la programación, donde un problema tiene múltiples soluciones. Fuera de eso, la solución propuesta es la más adecuada para tu caso.

Ejemplo (basado en lenguaje de programación *Java*):

> Escribir un método que permita evaluar si una palabra es palíndrome. El método recibe una cadena y deberá devolver un `boolean` indicando `true` si es palíndrome, de lo contrario se retorna `false`.

Dos alternativas a este problema:

- 1. Una sola sentencia:

     ```java
     public boolean esPalindrome(String s) {
         return new StringBuilder(
             s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase()
         ).reverse().toString().equals(s);
     }
     ```
- 2. Múltiples sentencias pero más óptimo en términos de memoria y tiempo de ejecución:

     ```java
     public boolean esPalindrome(String s) {
         s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
         boolean result = true;
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2 && result; i++) {
             result = s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1);
         }
         return result;
     }
     ```

Ambos compilan, ejecutan y pasan las pruebas unitarias mínimas de la implementación brindada (por ejemplo. **anita lava la tina**). ¿Cuál es más oficial o confiable? Asimismo, ¿Cuál de estas dos alternativas, sería una respuesta oficial? Aquí es donde sucede un gran debate (usando términos de *Java* para reforzar algunos puntos):

- ¿Y si ambas ofrecen enlaces a la documentación oficial de los métodos usados?
- ¿Y si ambas ofrecen enlaces a cómo funciona *Java* citando al *JLS (Java Language Specification)*?
- ¿Es importante que se muestre el análisis *Big* o de uso de memoria y de tiempo de ejecución? ¿Sirve también si se explica el *bytecode generado* y cómo el *JIT* incrementa el rendimiento del código?
- - ¿Influye saber que quien escribió el código es un programador experimentado con más de 5 años de experiencia?
  - ¿Influye si es un programador con solo 1 año de experiencia pero certificado en la tecnología?
  - ¿Influye si el programador, revisa y participa en la edición del código del último *JDK*?
- ¿Acaso es más **oficial** o **confiable** *por tener más votos/soporte de la comunidad* porque se ha compartido el enlace a la respuesta en múltiples sitios?

El punto al que quiero llegar es: Existen múltiples criterios y basados enteramente en la subjetividad para definir si una respuesta a un problema de programación es **oficial**.

Los únicos casos donde **yo** considero que existen respuestas oficiales es en *frameworks* o *plataformas* que poseen soporte oficial de una empresa (probablemente pagado), por ejemplo, *Bluemix*, *la nube de IBM*, y si tienes dudas respecto a la plataforma, *los desarrolladores de IBM* brindarán las respuestas oficiales en el sitio que ellos designen para dicho propósito, mientras que los desarrolladores experimentados en la plataforma brinden respuestas no oficiales pero muy probablemente confiables.

---

De tu último comentario en la respuesta:

> Lo que pregunto es, ¿*Stack Overflow* tiene alguna *politica* sobre esto?

Esto se explica en distintas partes de los [Términos de Servicio (enlace **legales** al pie de la página](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#warranties).

> Nota: Esta explicación ya no existe en los términos de servicio y la sección de renuncia de garantía ya no está en la *cláusula 5* si no que está en la *cláusula 7*.

A mi parecer, creo que este es el fragmento más relevante:

> 5. Warranty disclaimer
>
> (...)
>
> To the fullest extent allowed by law, Stack Exchange disclaims any liability or responsibility for the accuracy, reliability, availability, completeness, legality or operability of the material or services provided on this Network. By using this Network, you acknowledge that Stack Exchange is not responsible or liable for any harm resulting from (1) use of the Network; (2) downloading information contained on the Network including but not limited to downloads of content posted by subscribers; (3) unauthorized disclosure of images, information or data that results from the upload, download or storage of content posted by subscribers; (4) the temporary or permanent inability to access or retrieve any Subscriber Content from the Network, including, without limitation, harm caused by viruses, worms, trojan horses, or any similar contamination or destructive program.

Traducido (con algunas entradas mías para facilitar la comprensión):

> 5. Renuncia a la garantía.
>
> (...)
>
> En la mayor medida permitida por la ley, *Stack Exchange* declina toda obligación o responsabilidad por la exactitud, confiabilidad, disponibilidad, integridad, legalidad u operatividad del material o servicios proporcionados en esta *Red*. Al usar esta *Red*, usted reconoce que *Stack Exchange* no es responsable por cualquier daño que resulte de:
>
> 1. El uso de la Red.
> 2. Descargar información contenida en la *Red*, incluyendo, pero no limitado a la descarga de contenido publicado por los suscriptores, como las preguntas, respuestas o comentarios publicados por los usuarios de las comunidades.
> 3. La divulgación no autorizada de imágenes, información o datos que resulten de la carga, descarga o almacenamiento de contenido publicado por los suscriptores.
> 4. La incapacidad temporal o permanente de acceder o recuperar cualquier *Contenido de Suscriptor de la Red*, incluyendo, sin limitaciones, a daño causado por *viruses, gusanos, troyanos* o cualquier otro programa similar de contaminación o destrucción.

Es decir, que *Stack Exchange* no se hace responsable de que el contenido publicado en las preguntas o respuestas, sea oficial o confiable. Esto tiene mucho sentido, puesto que de lo contrario *Stack Exchange* estaría defendiendo las clásicas *preguntas/respuestas de "troll", insultos, publicación de ofertas de empleo* como preguntas o respuestas, *ofertas de venta de productos de software*, entre otras cosas.

Comment: gracias @Luiggi por tu respuesta, mi pregunta no estaba tan orientada a una solucion u otra. Mas bien a de donde se saca determinada solucion/informacion. Util la informacion sobre los terminos de servicio. O sea: No deberia preocuparme tanto sobre el origen de la informacion, mas bien estar satisfecho de haber brindado una alternativa de conocimiento?

Comment: El origen de la información también es importante, pero más importante es que puedas resolver el problema que tienes actualmente (al menos en el mundo laboral, en el mundo académico las reglas son muy diferentes).

Answer (score 3):

<sub>No veáis esta respuesta como un *Qué pesao el abuelo cebolleta* ;-)</sub>

Uno debe ser crítico cuando consulta datos en internet.

Imagina que eres administrador de sistemas y tienes un problema concreto con tu servidor. Entras en un foro y vas repitiendo lo que te comenta la gente. De repente, alguien dijo en plan broma que hagas <s>`rm -rf /`</s> (¡NO LO HAGÁIS NUNCA!), la pruebas y destruyes todos los datos. ¡Caramba, la hemos liado!

En los foros uno tendía a ir probando todo lo que iba apareciendo en la pantalla, sin importar qué validez tuviera. La gran ventaja de Stack Overflow (y uno de los motivos por el que surgió) es que las respuestas se clasifican por su utilidad ([Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83)) y no cronológicamente. Por tanto, uno espera que el paso del tiempo haga flotar las cosas buenas y hundir las que no lo son tanto, para que en el infinito, al final de los tiempos, lo bueno esté siempre arriba y lo malo apenas se vea.

¿Qué quiero decir con esto? Pues varias cosas:

- Prueba las cosas en entornos seguros. Crea tests, unittests, validaciones tontas, antes de dar por seguras las cosas que leas.
- En los temas que *sí* sabes, vota positiva y negativamente el contenido que leas. Añade respuestas, edita mejorando lo que veas que lo necesita. Le estarás haciendo un tremendo favor a los que vengan después de ti.
- En los temas que *no* sabes, sé escéptico. Prueba y comprueba, no te fíes ciegamente. Comenta si te fue bien, si te fue mal, si encuentras un error.

Debes imaginar Stack Overflow como una gran Wikipedia en constante construcción, de donde te puedes fiar pero sin dejar nunca de estar alerta.

Con esto estoy diciendo que Stack Overflow es uno de los lugares donde te puedes fiar bastante de lo que leas. Anima a más gente a unirse a ella, igual un día te encuentras al [creador de Python](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) y ese día le puedes preguntar algo directamente.

La documentación oficial también suele ser útil. En mi experiencia, también es útil llevar la quisquillosidad a GitHub, a Twitter... donde puedas estar en contacto con los creadores del código. Al fin y al cabo, son personas como tú, algunos programan gratuitamente su software, a otros les pagan sus empresas por hacerlo, y siempre es posible que se les pasen cosas.