# ¿Por qué se obtiene un voto negativo en respuesta marcada como solución?

Tags: soporte, respuesta, votos, respuesta-aceptada, respuesta-específica

Soy nuevo en esta comunidad y pude ver que al responder [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189679/centrar-encabezados-de-kartik-gridview-yii2/189968#189968), si bien fue marcada como válida por la persona que preguntó, me dieron un voto negativo.

No me interesa el voto, solo me gustaría que un usuario mas experimentado se tomara el trabajo de ver la publicación y brindar una explicación. De este modo me ayudaría a corregir mi error y evitar repetirlo en un futuro.

¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: aunque no fui yo quien votó negativo a tu respuesta, (de hecho la conozco recién) pudiera estar enfocado a que quien posteó la pregunta no lo hizo del modo adecuado, no coloco intentos ni errores; solo la petición de como se hizo y algunas veces esas preguntas no son bien recibidas por la comunidad; pues se pide en la medida de lo posible y aclaro en la medida de lo posible colocar todo intento hecho aunque tenga errores

Comment: Complementando el comentario de Alfredo, en esto hay una larga discusión al respecto en SOes, algunos tienen el criterio de votar negativamente la respuesta a una mala pregunta, tiene su razón en no promover estas castigando de alguna manera a quiénes las fomentan con sus respuestas, es un criterio comprensible. Otros, consideramos que respuesta y pregunta debieran ser evaluadas independientemente.  De cualquier forma, la pregunta estaba muy mal planteada, en estos caso siempre conviene pedir al OP que la mejore antes de responder, fíjate los comentarios de jorgesys al respecto. Saludos

Comment: En mi opinión no cometiste ningún error, hay preguntas muy puntuales que quienes han atravesado por esa situación no necesitan ver código para responder de manera clara concisa y directo al punto. Dependiendo de las zonas horarias vas a ver mas OCD en cuanto a ver código, intentos, investigación, etc... pasa nada, con el tiempo y mas participación esos bias se irán difuminando (pasó lo mismo en SO inglés hace casi una década). Si te aceptaron la respuesta, vale. Por la redacción de la pregunta es algo que va a saltar bastante en buscadores para quienes se inician en ese tema puntual.

Comment: Observando la hora del voto negativo (15.50) y la hora en la que se comentó en contra de la publicación, observo un patrón recurrente: votar negativamente las respuestas a preguntas malas. Creo que esto no está bien. Si bien no es bueno contestar preguntas malas hasta que se hayan mejorada, votar negativamente la respuesta está transmitiendo la idea de que la respuesta es incorrecta. Es decir, se está haciendo un meta-voto. Preocupante.

Comment: @fedorqui yo personalmente no suelo votar negativo este tipo de respuestas, sino que prefiero añadir un comentario al que responde explicándole porque no se deben responder preguntas que están mal planteadas, y más siendo un usuario mas o menos nuevo. Pero si bien es cierto que no se deberían votar negativamente, también es cierto que se observa que hay usuarios de muy alta reputación que también responden preguntas mal planteadas, y el voto negativo es la única forma que hay de darles un toque de atención. Yo no lo hago, pero entiendo que haya gente que si.

Comment: De todas maneras Fran, que una respuesta se marque como solución no es garantía de que sea una buena respuesta, o la mejor posible. Es el OP el que marca una solución como aceptada, pero el resto de usuarios tienen el derecho y la postestad de votar subjetivamente lo que quieran. Yo repito esto bastante, y es que no hay que dar tanta importancia a los votos ni buscarles explicación, ya que el que vota lo hace por razones de todo tipo y no tiene que dar explicaciones de ello.

Comment: Curiosamente, buscando la respuesta a otra pregunta, he encontrado [este ejemplo significativo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10581772/579895) de lo que decía. La respuesta aceptada tiene una puntuación de **10 votos negativos**, mientras que otra que no es la aceptada tiene una puntuación **106** :)

Comment: Es una actitud que se ha visto en muchísimas ocasiones, se castiga a la respuesta cuando la pregunta es mala, aunque no significa que la respuesta sea mala, no obstante, de igual manera el usuario que responde deberá pedir más información con ejemplos de código ya que este tipo de preguntas suelen ser demasiado amplias o no está claro lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Las votaciones negativas deberían tener, siempre, un mecanismo de retroalimentación (comentario o caracterización/tipificacion de las razones por las que se considera voto negativo) para que quien formuló el item (pregunta/respuesta) que esta siendo castigado pueda entender como mejorar sus aportes.

Comment: Creo que los puntos negativos perdidos por votaciones negativas a respuestas deberian restaurarse si el usuario que formula la pregunta acepta la respuesta. O restaurar la mitad de los puntos castigados si la respuesta castigada es retirada.

Answer (score 4):

## No lo sabemos y no lo vamos a saber.

Salvo que el autor del voto negativo ponga un comentario para explicarlo. Podríamos intentar especular :

- La pregunta tiene votos negativos, lo cual significa que hay quien piensa que es una mala pregunta. Hay quien piensa que responder preguntas malas anima a los usuarios a hacer preguntas malas. Hay quien piensa que animar a hacer preguntas malas perjudica al sitio y que es una buena idea dar votos negativos a quien lo hace para corregir ese comportamiento que, en opinión de ese alguien, es dañino para el sitio.
- Tu respuesta es un trozo de código con una explicación muy corta. Hay quien piensa que esto no es suficiente para que la respuesta sea de calidad.
- Puede que alguien se haya levantado de mal humor.

Nótese que el hecho de que una respuesta sea aceptada no significa que sea una buena respuesta, aunque sí es una indicación de que puede ser una buena respuesta. Solo significa que al autor de la pregunta le pareció que tu respuesta es la más útil. No todo el mundo tiene por qué estar de acuerdo con el autor de la pregunta y es perfectamente razonable votar negativo a una respuesta aceptada si piensas que es una mala respuesta.

Con respecto a tu error. Yo personalmente pienso que no has cometido ninguno. No pertenezco al grupo de quienes piensan hay que votar negativo a las buenas respuestas de malas preguntas. Tampoco pienso que tu respuesta sea mala. Suponiendo que tu respuesta técnica sea correcta (no lo se, no domino ese tema) me parece más que suficiente. Lo bueno si breve dos veces bueno.

Con lo que adelante. No te preocupes demasiado si recibes algún voto negativo. Querer satisfacer a todo el mundo es una receta segura para no conseguir nunca nada. Se tu mismo.

<strike>Como me parece muy mal que te voten negativo por esos motivos equivocados te he votado positivo para compensarlo pese a que no se si tu respuesta es técnicamente correcta.</strike> No hagamos esto, por favor. Como dice fedorqui, [votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83) ni por cómo han votado otros ni por nada más

Comment: [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83) ni por cómo han votado otros ni por nada más.