# En las respuestas a una pregunta, ¿se le da prioridad a la reputación del que contesta o al orden cronológico de las respuestas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, interfaz-de-usuario

Acabo de responder una pregunta cuya respuesta realmente no era tan compleja. Al cabo de unos 15 minutos, alguien con mas reputación respondió la misma pregunta de una forma un poco mas elaborada, pero esencialmente respondiendo lo mismo.

Lo curioso es que su respuesta (básicamente igual a la mía) se mostraba en primer lugar y la mía en segundo.

¿Si yo tuviera mas reputación, mi respuesta se mostraría de primero?

Comment: nop.. el orden es aleatorio cuando tienen el mismo puntaje las respuestas...

Comment: bah.. salvo que el usuario las ordene.. cosa que puede hacer..

Comment: @gbianchi muy interesante, y muy extraño. Como desarrollador, pensaría que el orden cronológico seria lo mas sensato.

Comment: nop.. porque no necesariamente la primera es la mejor...

Comment: @gbianchi si bueno, me refiero en el punto en que las respuestas tienen el mismo puntaje. Por supuesto que los votos determinan la mejor respuesta, lo cual es totalmente valido y es lo mejor. Pero mientras no existan votos, si estuviera a mi cargo, lo haría cronológico.

Comment: Entonces siempre estarias "premiando" a quien contesto mas rapido, por mas que no sea la mejor.. de esta forma, no hay orden cuando todas tienen el mismo puntaje, salvo que las ordenes. Habia un post al respecto en meta.se donde lo explicaban...

Comment: @gbianchi pero si la respuesta es la mejor, estarias penalizandola, por que hay un 50%-33.3%-25%  de probabilidad de que nunca salga hasta arriba y que la mayoria de personas nunca la mire. (y claro que estas probabilidades son bastante altas, incluso la de 25%). Digo, no mucho me importa, pero es interesante discutir estas peculiaridades del StackExchange.

Comment: Por supuesto, usuarios experimentados con el sitio, revisarían todas las respuestas antes de dar el voto, pero no todos lo hacen, creo que eso es lo mas curioso del caso. Creo que los 2 casos tienen sus ventajas y desventajas.

Comment: Si la respuesta es buena, va a ser votada y va a subir solita. El caso es solamente al poner las respuestas. Pero luego de eso, ya solas se acomodan. Usuarios no experimentados no suelen revisar respuestas recientes.

Comment: Que se ordenen de forma cronológica (o sólo por votos) lleva al problema del ["Pistolero más rápido del Oeste"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Como se indica en esa pregunta y respuestas, existen métodos más efectivos (y complejos) para resolver el problema que basarse sólo en un parámetro.

Comment: Conozco un par de usuarios en esta comunidad (y de hecho tienen buena reputación) que parece que hacen lo que sea por responder de primeros (creo que ni duermen), y en general considero que sus respuestas son de baja calidad, los OP les agradecen como si les salvaran la vida, y posteriormente llegan buenas respuestas de otros usuarios que muchas veces terminan ignoradas. Todo esto para decir que lo de responder de primero no te hace ni debería hacerte el mejor, necesitas mucho más que eso en la vida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las respuestas se pueden ordenar de tres maneras:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- ***activas***: muestra primero la última en ser actualizada
- ***más antiguas***: muestra primero la que primero se publicó
- ***votos***: muestra primero la que tiene más puntuación. En caso de igualdad, las ordena aleatoriamente. **Esta es la opción por defecto**.

Si bien siempre aparecerá arriba del todo la respuesta aceptada (siempre y cuando no sea una respuesta publicada por el autor de la pregunta).

Como ves, la reputación de los usuarios que contestaron no se tiene nunca en cuenta.

---

El caso que comentas es algo peliagudo y habría que ver exactamente cómo son las respuestas. En cualquier caso, si alguien publica una respuesta igual que la tuya bastante después, creo que lo primero que puedes hacer es comentar en su respuesta advirtiéndoselo. Si no surge efecto (es decir, si no hace alguna de estas cosas: editar refiriendo a tu respuesta, eliminar su respuesta o modificarla de modo que no sea tan igual a la tuya), lo suyo es reportarlo a los moderadores para que lo gestionen. Lo que yo no haría es votar negativamente, por aquello de que [siempre debemos votar por contenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83), y se supone que el contenido es bueno.